# IOS app background to foreground

Tags: ios

I am working in an ios app,that runs in background mode. How should I fetch the app from background to foreground when the battery percentage change?

Comment: Will you please specify what kind of app this is?

Comment: First of all, you need a basic understanding of what iOS lets you do and blocks you from doing. This almost certainly falls in the second category.

Comment: My app is running in the background. According to  my requirement, suppose the app is currently in the background mode and at that time if the device got connected with it's charger, in this scenario the app will automatically come to foreground.Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Apple will not let you do that with its public APIs. If anything you could maybe read up on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20) and run some background code.

Besides, with this application, I guess you would be waiting until the battery runs low, which may take a long time. This the device will terminate the application (and you can't even do anything).